# Scalatest: should be Matchers with extra description?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have a `org.scalatest.FunSpec with org.scalatest.Matchers` test that does the following e.g.

```
val tol = 1e-10
val res = 1.000000000000001
val ref = 1.000000000000000
res should be (ref +- tol)
```

but it does so in a loop for multiple cases keyed by name, of course I can't change the granularity of the tested code so I get a collection of values with those names associated to them. Therefore for a test above I need to place an extra context or extra description `name` to reflect to which name it applies. I need something like:

```
val name : String = ...
res should be (ref +- tol) for name
```

I can't use `it` and `describe` at this point because they are already outside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really depends on what you're trying to do, and you should probably add a more complete example of what you're trying to achieve, but you could use `describe` in the loop. For example:

```
class TempTest extends FunSpec with Matchers {

  describe("Some example test") {

    (1 to 10).foreach { i => // your loop here

      describe(s"Scenario $i") {
        it("should be equal to itself") {
          i shouldBe i
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:** You could use `withClue` to add more context to the matcher e.g.:

```
withClue("Some clarifying message") {
    i shouldBe 5
}
```

This will add the clue string to the error if the conditions fails.

Comment: Good but suppose I can't do that ... we have a scalatest extension that sends tests to be computed remotely in a cluster ... this framework already takes hold of the outtermost `describe ` and automatically wraps each test in an `it` that describes it so ... I need a way to attach the text `name` to the `res should be (ref +- tol)` condition ... maybe the only way is by catching and enriching the potential `TestFailedException` ... and of course moving to `assertResult` is another possibility simply give up the Should Matcher

Comment: @GiovanniAzua would the example in the update help you?

Comment: That's it, you nailed it :) I'm really happy that scalatest is designed in a way that almost no real life scenario is left uncovered :D

Answer (score 1):

Probably GivenWhenThen can be used in order to add context to the tests reporting. I am not sure how exactly you wrap your multiple tests in the loop, but here is the idea:

```
import org.scalatest.{GivenWhenThen, WordSpec}

/**
  * Created by alex on 10/3/16.
  */
class Temp extends WordSpec with GivenWhenThen{
  val names = List("Alex", "Dana")
  for(name <- names)yield{
    "Reversing a name " + name + " two times" should {
      "result in the same name" in{
        Given("name " + name)
        When("reversed two times")
        val reversed = name.reverse.reverse
        Then("it should be the same")
        assert(name === reversed)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a good pointer however, then I have to give up the best context error produced by `res should be (ref +- tol)` and instead use assert . I can also switch to assert directly without `GivenWhenThen`